# What happens to money in ISA after the tax year ends?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

The [Individual Savings Account](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts) scheme allows UK residents to save up to £20,000 tax-free each year in an ISA. The interest, income or capital gains from this account are **tax-free**.

---

Suppose I have put £20k in my ISA, and due to gains it is now worth £21k. What happens to this money after the 2017-2018 tax year ends and the 2018-2019 starts?

- Do I have to withdraw the £21k and start a new ISA from scratch?
- Or can I accumulate a further £20k into this account the following year, reaching a total of £41k in the account, all of it netting tax-free gains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ISAs last for as long as you live - you can accumulate a further £20K each following year (or whatever the limit changes to) and the whole balance including gains is tax free.

You can also leave the £21k in the first ISA, and open a new ISA the next year, if you prefer. You can also transfer a balance from one ISA to another (make sure you go through the explicit process for doing that, don't just withdraw it and re-deposit it, otherwise the protection is lost.)

Comment: And if you keep going for long enough and invest astutely enough, you could join the ranks of the [ISA millionaires](http://www.independent.co.uk/money/tax/can-tax-free-savers-become-millionaires-8507857.html)